# Changing page content from a modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using a [plugin](https://github.com/marcosesperon/Messi) for modal window. What I am doing is, clicking on an anchor, modal shows and displays clicked anchor text in an input field to enable user changing it. What I want to do is, as user type new anchor text to input field inside the modal, let anchor text changes as-you-type inside the main page. Need advice to reach main page from a modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plugin only creates an additional `<div>` on the bottom of your `<body>` tag (see the classes' names using inspect element). it is still in the same file. so you can access the anchor's id using jQuery selector. set the text using `$("#yourAnchorID").html("your new text")`

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the reference of the clicked anchor tag to your plugin and change the content of anchor tag as user types in the input field.